# Passing field name and table name for query in php function?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to pass the name of field and table as an argument in php function so that i can use those values in my query.

```
function finder($v1, $v2){
        $mid=0; $nid=-5; $v11='go';
        include'connect.php';
        $query1=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MAX(id) FROM users_allow");
        WHILE($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query1))
        {
            $mid = $row['0'];
        }
}
finder('id', 'users_allow');
```

How the query should be changed to adopt the name of field and the table from the arguments passed to the function. i had tried v1, v2 in single quote in the query but does not work, Problem remain as how to use these two variable (v1 and v2) as filed name and table name in MySQL Query.

Comment: [Binding parameters to your statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: I want it as "" $query1=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MAX($v1) FROM $v2"); ""  but this does not work

Comment: Why, then just do it! `'SELECT MAX('.$v1.') FROM '.$v2`. What happens when it "does not work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of following

```
function finder($v1, $v2){
        $mid=0; $nid=-5; $v11='go';
        include'connect.php';
        //way one:
        $query1=mysqli_query($con, sprintf("SELECT MAX(%d) FROM %s",$v1,$v2));
        //way two: this will only work with the string inside ""
        $query1=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MAX({v1}) FROM {$v2}");
        WHILE($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query1))
        {
            $mid = $row['0'];
        }
}
finder('id', 'users_allow');
```